# Mongo FindAsync Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, mongodb

With C# and Mongo I am trying to do the following

```
using (var cursor = await MongoCollection.FindAsync(query, findOptions)){
    return await cursor.ToListAsync();
}
```

it started to throw the error "Nullable object must have a value"

To troubleshoot inside the using statement I converted to this

```
while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
```

it appears to randomly on the MoveNextAsync() to throw the exception

If I convert to the non-async Find,  I seem to get all my objects back correctly.

Digging more into this, I seem to be getting this error if the FindOption has limit set. Sort and Skip seems to work just fine.

Comment: It's known error. Update you MongoDB to version 3.2 or higher.

Comment: this issue did not happen till I upgraded to version 3.2.  before this issue I was running 3.06 on windows, I just recently moved to 3.2 on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I have just received this error.

Upgrading in NuGet to the 2.2.1 C# driver fixed it for me.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.2.1